# MySQL query between 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck in this MySQL query. I get way too many results.

```
SELECT 
    un.user_uid, 
    un.notification_date, 
    un.notification_text, 
    un.notification_type, 
    un.post_id, 
    up.user_uid AS notification_user_uid, 
    uu.user_username
FROM user_notifications un
    LEFT JOIN
    user_posts_comments up
    ON 
        up.post_id = un.post_id
    LEFT JOIN
    user_user uu
    ON 
        up.user_uid = uu.user_uid
WHERE
    un.notification_status = 1 AND
    un.user_uid = '2536'
ORDER BY un.notification_date DESC
```

I have a table UN that contains the post_id, I look in the UP for the same post_id and get the user_uid, than I look in the UU table for the user_username.
But this way I get duplicate results (I know why but don't find how I can resolve it.

This is the result I need:

| **un.user_uid** | **un.notification_date** | **un.notification_text** | **un.notification_type** | **un.post_id** | **notification_user_id** | **uu.user_username** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2536 | 2023-02-01 | Text 1 | 1 | AZ325B | 2530 | John |
| 2536 | 2023-02-01 | Text 2 | 1 | BZ826C | 2530 | John |
| 2536 | 2023-02-01 | Text 3 | 1 | CC724E | 2489 | Sarah |
| 2536 | 2023-02-01 | Text 4 | 1 | AB234F | 2358 | Beth |

These are the tables I have:

##### user_notifications

| **un.user_uid** | **un.notification_date** | **un.notification_text** | **un.notification_type** | **un.post_id** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2536 | 2023-02-01 | Text 1 | 1 | AZ325B |
| 2536 | 2023-02-02 | Text 2 | 1 | BZ826C |
| 2536 | 2023-02-03 | Text 3 | 1 | CC724E |
| 2536 | 2023-02-04 | Text 4 | 1 | AB234F |
| 2489 | 2023-02-05 | Text 5 | 1 | ZA256R |
| 2489 | 2023-02-06 | Text 6 | 1 | TR856D |
| 2580 | 2023-02-07 | Text 7 | 1 | AQ156R |
| 2596 | 2023-02-08 | Text 8 | 1 | BE895V |
| 2573 | 2023-02-09 | Text 9 | 1 | UY853Z |

##### user_posts_comments

| **un.post_id** | **un.post_text** |
| --- | --- |
| AZ325B | Hello this is post 1 |
| BZ826C | Hello this is post 2 |
| CC724E | Hello this is post 3 |
| AB234F | Hello this is post 4 |
| ZA256R | Hello this is post 5 |
| TR856D | Hello this is post 6 |
| AQ156R | Hello this is post 7 |
| BE895V | Hello this is post 8 |
| UY853Z | Hello this is post 9 |

##### user_user

| **uu.uid** | **uu.user_username** |
| --- | --- |
| 2530 | John |
| 2358 | Beth |
| 2489 | Sarah |
| 2536 | Tom |
| 2573 | David |

Comment: What are your current results? So you want to only receive the comments of a single user?

Comment: You have `user_user uu ON up.user_uid = uu.user_uid` but no `user_uid` on the `user_posts_comments` in your sample data. You have `un.notification_status = 1` in your WHERE clause but no status column in your sample data. You say you _"know why"_ but don't go on to explain what you think the problem is.

Comment: You may want to explore using `GROUP BY` to group results by the ID of a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inner join` instead of `left join`. I guess that way you'd get only overlapping tuples between tables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).